# How to get instance of typescript class inside a model?

Tags: angular, typescript, oop

I'm new on TypeScript, I'm trying to get a class instance.

This my code:

```
    export class Location {

      name: string;
      tone: string;
      owner: string;
      rooms: Array < any > ;

      constructor(
        public auth: AuthProvider
      ) {
        this.setDefault();
      }

      setDefault() {
        this.name = '';
        this.tone = 'default';
        this.owner = this.auth.auth.auth.currentUser.uid;
        this.rooms = [];
      }

      getInstance(){
        //how to return instance of the class value
      }
      setName(){
      this.name = "Demo";
  }

  getName(){
      return this.name;
  }
    }
```

So after setting location name using setName() I need to get a location instance that contain all location data name, owner ...

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: `return this`? Sorry, but I can't understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new instance of the Location class you then can access the properties you set in the constructor without needing a `getInstance()`.

`var location = new Location ()`
`location.setName()` then you can access the tone like `location.tone`